# how do i disable the default unity thing that makes it so that it closes the game when you click the escape key

Tags: unity-game-engine

when i make my game on unity 2021.3.15f1, whenever i click the escape key the game closes, but i want the escape key to pause to the menu, not close the game.

i asked chatgpt and it told me about an option called "exit on suspend" that i didnt find where it told me to ("Edit" -> "Project Settings" -> "Player")

Comment: the game doesnt by default quit on escape - alt+f4 sure...

Answer (score 0):

In your entire solution, CTRL + Shift + F and look for "Application.quit()".

There is a possibility the quitting mechanism is somewhere in your project like:

```cs
if (Input.GetKey("escape"))
{
  Application.Quit();
}
```

If you find none, then simply add this code block to an empty object in your scene with slight alterations:

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
 
// Pause the game when the user hits escape
 
public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey("escape"))
        {
        // Open your pause menu here instead of quitting the game.
        }
    }
}
```

Credits: https://forum.unity.com/threads/quitting-game-by-pressing-esc-escape-key.562033/